# Refactoring a for loop into a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How to change this for loop into stream?

```
public int calculateForSpliterator(String[] matchTab, String spliterator, RulesChecker rulesChecker) {
    int finalScore = 0;
    for (String element : matchTab) {
        String[] splitScroes = element.split(spliterator);
        int ourPoints = Integer.parseInt(splitScroes[0]);
        int theirPoints = Integer.parseInt(splitScroes[1]);
        finalScore += rulesChecker.checkRules(ourPoints, theirPoints);
    }
    return finalScore;
}
```

Comment: If the code works as you expect it to, do you need to change it to use a `Stream`? Sure it'll probably look nice, but will it benefit functionality or performance in any way?

Comment: @mohammedkhan no but after reading an answaer I was sure in it that it won't be more readable. Before answear i could just guess cuz didn't know how it will looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `RulesChecker#checkRules` returns an `int`, then you can use:

```
public int calculateForSpliterator(String[] matchTab, String spliterator, RulesChecker rulesChecker) {
    return Arrays.stream(matchTab)
        .map(element -> element.split(spliterator))
        .mapToInt(splitScores -> rulesChecker.checkRules(Integer.parseInt(splitScores[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(splitScores[1])))
        .sum();
}
```

Notice how this isn't much more readable than your current solution, so I probably would keep the for-loop if I were you.